# Algorithm for generating n X n nonisomorphic binary matrices

Tags: python, c, algorithm, matrix

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1 << 4; i++)
    {
        printf("%d %d\n", (i >> 0) & 1, (i >> 1) & 1);
        printf("%d %d\n", (i >> 2) & 1, (i >> 3) & 1);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

There are 2^(n^2) possible binary matrix of n×n, isomorphic means the symmetry operations of rotation and reflection of the board are counted as one.
For example, there are 6 nonisomorphic 2 X 2 matrices,

[0 0] [0 0] [0 0] [0 1] [0 1] [1 1]
[0 0] [0 1] [1 1] [1 0] [1 1] [1 1].

[image]
What's the efficient way for generating such n X n binary matrix in python or C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do for trying to answer is counting the number of combinations for 3x3.

You have to distinguish 3 classes of cells:

1. the center that is invariant wrt rotation/reflexion
2. the 4 edges
3. the 4 corners

Since center is invariant, it is completely independent, so we will have to multiply by 2 the number of solutions excluding center

```
x x x     x x x
x 0 x  +  x 1 x
x x x     x x x
```

There are 6 different combinations of corners:

```
0 x 0   1 x 0   1 x 1   1 x 0   1 x 1   1 x 1
x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x   x
0 x 0   0 x 0   0 x 0   0 x 1   1 x 0   1 x 1
```

Same for edges. We can now examine the combinations of the edges and corners, for this I take a table with number of pieces set to 1.
Note that placing 1s or placing 0s is the same problem, so we have a symmetry of rows and columns...
I don't give the detail of combinations, just the number of different combinations I found:

```
x   0 1 2 3 4

0   1 1 2 1 1
1   1 2 4 2 1
2   2 4 7 4 2
3   1 2 4 2 1
4   1 1 2 1 1
```

So that's 51, multiplied by 2 when combining with center, so 102 combinations.

Now that we know the first 3 terms of the serie, we can go on OEIS and search for matching `2,6,102`.

https://oeis.org/search?q=2%2C6%2C102&sort=&language=french&go=Chercher

We find https://oeis.org/A054247

> Number of n X n binary matrices under action of dihedral group of the
>   square D_4

I won't continue further, the problem is a bit hard for putting a whole answer here, but at least you now have links for finding by yourself...